# is space-track.org a free service?

Tags: debris, tracking

Is the website [space-track.org](http://space-track.org) a free service ? 
If not can someone give other free website to track space debris.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is free, however, you have create an account, and the request must be approved. You have to include a reason on the account to request it. There are quite a few acceptable reasons, however, so feel free to create an account if you wish, many of which aren't really professional at all.

Another service that doesn't require an account, but is quite useful, is https://celestrak.org/ . They may get their information direction from the operators, so it might even be more accurate then space-track.

Comment: My request to Space-track was approved within a few seconds. So may be they are not really checking the reasons. I registered with an @edu mail address.

Comment: Maybe it depends on the category? In any case, good to know.