# During ascent, can SPACE-X ever be seen from Long Island, NY?

Tags: spacex, launch, exhaust

At night I have seen Space Shuttles' engine exhaust from Long Island NY, in the southeast sky 7 minutes after liftoff from the Cape. Does Space-X ever launch in a direction that it can be seen from Long Island, NY?

Comment: @WarrenBackyardAstronomer At what location on Long Island were you able to view the Shuttle's exhaust during ascent?

Comment: Recommended reading: [How can Flightclub.io Camera Tools be used to simulate launch photography geometry?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/26686/12102) and [this answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/25715/12102).

Comment: Just out of interest, have you calculated the minimum altitude at which you have LOS to a launch, assuming minimal change of latitude for the rocket?

Comment: Shuttle night launches were easily visible from the entire US Atlantic seaboard.  https://cdn.mos.cms.futurecdn.net/xD68xYrQueJgnojh9AFHij-650-80.jpg