# How can I know which direction a launch will be?

Tags: launch, trajectory

I'm in SOUTH FLORIDA and try to watch all the launches from here.  Sometimes, the rocket seems to head south and come right overhead.  How can I tell what direction a launch will take?  Thank you.  M

Comment: similar and potentially helpful: [How can I find sources for Launch Trajectories?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/25710/12102)