# Obtain archived TLE data

Tags: two-line-elements

Now I'm achieving the up-to-date TLE from the [celestrak.com](https://celestrak.org) and [tle.info](http://tle.info)

However, for some analysis in the past, I need old TLE files, to make my calculations more accurate.

Is there a way to obtain the archived TLE data? Is there a way to do it via URL (to be able to load from the script, like `celestrak.com/cgi-bin/TLE.pl?CATNR=40052&DATE=...`)?

Comment: See this answer: https://space.stackexchange.com/a/24445/12102 Also, for some selected groups of satellites, Celestrak has some archives as well: https://www.celestrak.com/NORAD/elements/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Celestrak

For some selected groups of satellites, Celestrak has already-built group definitions of satellite archives at https://celestrak.org/NORAD/elements/

[image]

### Space-Track

Another option is to subscribe to [Space-Track.org](https://www.space-track.org). You have to register using your name and e-mail address, then verify, but it is a straightforward process. Make sure to read all of the instructions and rules first.

Read the USER AGREEMENT first!

Then at least browse everything else.

[image]

You can read more about using Space-Track in [this answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/24445/12102)

One you are registered and logged in, select `TLE search` from the top menu:

[image]

Then enter the satellite number (21639 for example) and click all of the options shown below, and you will get all of the TLEs so far for March, 2018.

[image]

If you click the blue `API` button, it will *build a URL for you* and then open it in a new tab. You can save that URL and alter it or rebuild it later with Python.

You can also save the data in the new tab directly from File->Save on your browser.

Read the instructions in more depth if you want to try to do this automatically from a script. Visit `HowTo` from the `Help` menu: https://www.space-track.org/documentation#/howto

[image]

### Finally

Remember you need to use your personal log-in before you can access the site, *even using a script*, and remember to

### Follow All Rules

Answer (score 2):

Here is a sample Python script I modified from the [example](https://www.space-track.org/documentation#howto-api_python) at Space-Track.org (requires registration of a free account).  It looks for all SpaceLink satellites only (I plan to modify it to accept a list or dictionary with resident space object identifiers instead):

```
# STTest.py (copyright 2019 by Andrew Stokes, original file named differently)
#
# Simple Python app to extract resident space object history data from www.space-track.org into a spreadsheet
# (prior to executing, register for a free personal account at https://www.space-track.org/auth/createAccount)
#
# This program is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify it
# under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by the Free Software Foundation,
# either version 3 of the License, or (at your option) any later version.
#
# This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful, but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY;
# without even the implied warranty of MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
# See the GNU General Public License for more details.
#
# For full licencing terms, please refer to the GNU General Public License (gpl-3_0.txt) distributed with this release,
# or see http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-3.0.html.

import requests
import json
import xlsxwriter
import time
import datetime
import getpass
import sys

class MyError(Exception):
    def __init___(self, args):
        Exception.__init__(self, "my exception was raised with arguments {0}".format(args))
        self.args = args

# See https://www.space-track.org/documentation for details on REST queries
# "Find Starlinks" query finds all satellites w/ NORAD_CAT_ID > 40000 & OBJECT_NAME matching STARLINK*, 1 line per sat;
# the "OMM Starlink" query gets all Orbital Mean-Elements Messages (OMM) for a specific NORAD_CAT_ID in JSON format.

uriBase = "https://www.space-track.org"
requestLogin = "/ajaxauth/login"
requestCmdAction = "/basicspacedata/query"
requestFindStarlinks = "/class/tle_latest/NORAD_CAT_ID/>40000/ORDINAL/1/OBJECT_NAME/STARLINK~~/format/json/orderby/NORAD_CAT_ID%20asc"
requestOMMStarlink1 = "/class/omm/NORAD_CAT_ID/"
requestOMMStarlink2 = "/orderby/EPOCH%20asc/format/json"

# Parameters to derive apoapsis and periapsis from mean motion (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_motion)
GM = 398600441800000.0
GM13 = GM ** (1.0 / 3.0)
MRAD = 6378.137
PI = 3.14159265358979
TPI86 = 2.0 * PI / 86400.0

# Log in to personal account obtained by registering for free at https://www.space-track.org/auth/createAccount
print('\nEnter your personal Space-Track.org username (usually your email address for registration):  ')
configUsr = input()
print('Username capture complete.\n')
configPwd = getpass.getpass(prompt='Securely enter your Space-Track.org password (minimum of 15 characters):  ')
# Excel Output file name - e.g. starlink-track.xlsx (note: make it an .xlsx file)
configOut = 'STText.xslx'
siteCred = {'identity': configUsr, 'password': configPwd}

# User xlsxwriter package to write the .xlsx file
print('Creating Microsoft Excel (.xlsx) file to contain outputs...')
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook(configOut)
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
z0_format = workbook.add_format({'num_format': '#,##0'})
z1_format = workbook.add_format({'num_format': '#,##0.0'})
z2_format = workbook.add_format({'num_format': '#,##0.00'})
z3_format = workbook.add_format({'num_format': '#,##0.000'})

# write the headers on the spreadsheet
print('Starting to write outputs to Excel file create...')
now = datetime.datetime.now()
nowStr = now.strftime("%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S")
worksheet.write('A1', 'Starlink data from' + uriBase + " on " + nowStr)
worksheet.write('A3', 'NORAD_CAT_ID')
worksheet.write('B3', 'SATNAME')
worksheet.write('C3', 'EPOCH')
worksheet.write('D3', 'Orb')
worksheet.write('E3', 'Inc')
worksheet.write('F3', 'Ecc')
worksheet.write('G3', 'MnM')
worksheet.write('H3', 'ApA')
worksheet.write('I3', 'PeA')
worksheet.write('J3', 'AvA')
worksheet.write('K3', 'LAN')
worksheet.write('L3', 'AgP')
worksheet.write('M3', 'MnA')
worksheet.write('N3', 'SMa')
worksheet.write('O3', 'T')
worksheet.write('P3', 'Vel')
wsline = 3


def countdown(t, step=1, msg='Sleeping...'):  # in seconds
    pad_str = ' ' * len('%d' % step)
    for i in range(t, 0, -step):
        sys.stdout.write('{} for the next {} seconds {}\r'.format(msg, i, pad_str))
        sys.stdout.flush()
        time.sleep(step)
    print('Done {} for {} seconds!  {}'.format(msg, t, pad_str))

# use requests package to drive the RESTful session with space-track.org
print('Interfacing with SpaceTrack.org to obtain data...')
with requests.Session() as session:

    # Need to log in first. NOTE:  we get a 200 to say the web site got the data, not that we are logged in.
    resp = session.post(uriBase + requestLogin, data=siteCred)
    if resp.status_code != 200:
        raise MyError(resp, "POST fail on login.")

    # This query picks up all Starlink satellites from the catalog. NOTE: a 401 failure shows you have bad credentials.
    resp = session.get(uriBase + requestCmdAction + requestFindStarlinks)
    if resp.status_code != 200:
        print(resp)
        raise MyError(resp, "GET fail on request for resident space objects.")

    # Use json package to break json-formatted response into a Python structure (a list of dictionaries)
    retData = json.loads(resp.text)
    satCount = len(retData)
    satIds = []
    for e in retData:
        # each e describes the latest elements for one resident space object. We just need the NORAD_CAT_ID...
        catId = e['NORAD_CAT_ID']
        satIds.append(catId)

    # Using our new list of resident space object NORAD_CAT_IDs, we can now get the OMM message
    maxs = 1 # counter for number of sessions we have established without a pause in querying space-track.org
    for s in satIds:
        resp = session.get(uriBase + requestCmdAction + requestOMMStarlink1 + s + requestOMMStarlink2)
        if resp.status_code != 200:
            # If you are getting error 500's here, its probably the rate throttle on the site (20/min and 200/hr)
            # wait a while and retry
            print(resp)
            raise MyError(resp, "GET fail on request for resident space object number " + s + '.')

        # the data here can be quite large, as it's all the elements for every entry for one resident space object
        retData = json.loads(resp.text)
        for e in retData:
            # each element is one reading of the orbital elements for one resident space object
            print("Scanning satellite " + e['OBJECT_NAME'] + " at epoch " + e['EPOCH'] + '...')
            mmoti = float(e['MEAN_MOTION'])
            ecc = float(e['ECCENTRICITY'])
            worksheet.write(wsline, 0, int(e['NORAD_CAT_ID']))
            worksheet.write(wsline, 1, e['OBJECT_NAME'])
            worksheet.write(wsline, 2, e['EPOCH'])
            worksheet.write(wsline, 3, float(e['REV_AT_EPOCH']))
            worksheet.write(wsline, 4, float(e['INCLINATION']), z1_format)
            worksheet.write(wsline, 5, ecc, z3_format)
            worksheet.write(wsline, 6, mmoti, z1_format)
            # do some ninja-fu to flip Mean Motion into Apoapsis and Periapsis, and to get orbital period and velocity
            sma = GM13 / ((TPI86 * mmoti) ** (2.0 / 3.0)) / 1000.0
            apo = sma * (1.0 + ecc) - MRAD
            per = sma * (1.0 - ecc) - MRAD
            smak = sma * 1000.0
            orbT = 2.0 * PI * ((smak ** 3.0) / GM) ** (0.5)
            orbV = (GM / smak) ** (0.5)
            worksheet.write(wsline, 7, apo, z1_format)
            worksheet.write(wsline, 8, per, z1_format)
            worksheet.write(wsline, 9, (apo + per) / 2.0, z1_format)
            worksheet.write(wsline, 10, float(e['RA_OF_ASC_NODE']), z1_format)
            worksheet.write(wsline, 11, float(e['ARG_OF_PERICENTER']), z1_format)
            worksheet.write(wsline, 12, float(e['MEAN_ANOMALY']), z1_format)
            worksheet.write(wsline, 13, sma, z1_format)
            worksheet.write(wsline, 14, orbT, z0_format)
            worksheet.write(wsline, 15, orbV, z0_format)
            wsline = wsline + 1
        maxs = maxs + 1
        print(str(maxs))
        if maxs > 18:
            print('\nSnoozing for 60 secs for rate limit reasons (max 20/min and 200/hr).')
            countdown(60)
            maxs = 1
    session.close()
workbook.close()
print('\nCompleted session.')
```

The name of the original script by Andrew Stokes was "SLTrack.py" which I renamed to "STTest.py" because I am still playing around with it. I do not care about any copyright attribution to myself.

Comment: brethvoice, thanks for adding back in the proper attribution. It'd also be best if you included in your answer the location of the original source code (https://www.space-track.org/documentation#/howto) and the name of the original script. If you would like, you can add a copyright for the modifications to attribute them to you (see how to do that [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/158011/253910)).

Comment: Hi @called2voyage, thank you for the kind assistance.  The name of the original script by A. Stokes was `SLTrack.py' which I renamed to `STTest.py' because I am still playing around with it.  I do not care about any copyright attribution to myself.

Comment: Thanks! And welcome to the community!