# Why are there some NORAD catalog IDs larger than 80000 in space-track?

Tags: two-line-elements, space-track

I was trying to find the international designator for the Starlink-2 constellation launch. Not finding anything in Celestrak I looked in Space-Track.

The following space-track.org query builder setup generated the following query.

https://www.space-track.org/basicspacedata/query/class/tle_latest/NORAD_CAT_ID/%3E44700/orderby/NORAD_CAT_ID%20asc/limit/5000/format/tle/emptyresult/show

It gives me the latest TLEs for objects with NORAD catalogue IDs above `44700`, sorted by international designator. The series goes up to `44712` then  jumps to `81014` and lists several thousand more designators, ending at `89496`.

Many of them above `80000` have no epochs, but some have epoch years of 1983 or 1970.

**Question:**  Why are there some NORAD catalog IDs larger than 80000 in space-track?

---

Here are a few snippets of a few columns. Space-Track requires registration to access data. To register for (the free) access see [this answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/26294/12102).

> [image: some tles]  [image: some tles]
>
> [image]
>
> [image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are so called "Analyst" objects:

> Analyst objects are on-orbit objects that are tracked by the U.S.
> Space Surveillance Network (SSN) with insufficient fidelity for
> publication in the public satellite catalog (SATCAT). The lack of
> fidelity may be due to infrequent tracking, cross-tagging (observation
> association with closely-spaced objects), or inability to associate
> the object with a known launch. Today there are approximately 17,000
> on-orbit objects in the public SATCAT and approximately 6,000 on-orbit
> analyst objects for a total of 23,000. ...  The analyst range, which is denoted by a satellite number from 80,000-89,999, is used like an analytical sandbox

Source: Space Track [documentation](https://www.space-track.org/documentation#faq)

Celestrak keeps a nice list of all Analyst objects and the age of their TLE's [here](https://celestrak.org/satcat/analyst-catalog.php).

And, of course, for all things TLE I strongly suggest following T.S. Kelso on [Twitter](https://twitter.com/TSKelso)

Comment: Excellent answer, thank you! I'm surprised that I've never seen these before yesterday.

Comment: fyi I've just asked [Why is the NORAD Calatog number of SpaceX's Starlink's “Darksat” both 71130 and 44972?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/40892/12102)

Comment: Celestrak ***no longer*** keeps a nice list of all Analyst objects and the age of their TLE's there :-(