# Where can I find an up-to-date report on the Hubble Telescope's orbital history and current altitude?

Tags: hubble

I haven't been able to find a current report on the state of Hubble's orbital decay and I'm hoping someone can direct me to that info.  The satellite tracker sites just present an average or estimate that hasn't changed in the last decade.

Answer (score 5):

[This tracker](http://www.infosatellites.com/hst-satellite-tracking-norad-20580.html) seems to show lat long and altitude with timestamp.

You can find more information from TLEs.
[This page](https://isstracker.pl/en/satelity/20580#tle) seems to show the current TLE, orbit history(including decay), inclination and so on.

[image: TLEs and altitude history]
[Image ref](https://isstracker.pl/en/satelity/20580#tle)

<s>Not sure how precisely you need the attitude, but pages such as [this one](https://spacetelescopelive.org/latest) show what HST is currently looking at. In principal one could guess the attitude from that.</s> (Correcting since it was pointed out that attitude wasnt mentioned in OP.)

Hope this helps!

Comment: @BrendanLuke15 thanks for pointing it out, corrected now. :)

Answer (score 4):

So long as you don't intend to "*transfer any data or technical information received from this website, or other U.S. Government source, including the analysis of data, to any other entity without prior express approval. See, 10 USC 2274(c)(2)*" You can use [Space-Track.Org](https://www.space-track.org/) to find a [TLE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-line_element_set)  history ([See this answer for more details](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/26294/40257)).

**Self plug:** you can also use this [TLE- Decoder Converter tool](https://brendanluke15.github.io/TLE-Decoder-Converter/TLE-2-CSV-Utility.html) that I made ([Github link](https://github.com/BrendanLuke15/TLE-Decoder-Converter)) to plot the mean elements against one another to get something like this:

[image: ISS altitude history]

(*note that this is an ISS altitude history using [data obtained from Celestrak](https://celestrak.org/NORAD/archives/), for the reasons stated above I cannot share one of Hubble*)

Comment: that TLE decoder is really cool!